# iOS memory management UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, uiimage

if `UIImage` is an autorelease object, why when I analyze does it complain that on the 2nd line below there is a potential leak stored to `image`:

```
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: ImageURL];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: data];

    [data release];
    // Do we want to round the corners?
    image = [self roundCorners: image];

    // Is it PNG or JPG/JPEG?
    // Running the image representation function writes the data from the image to a file
    if([ImageURLString rangeOfString: @".png" options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile: uniquePath atomically: YES];
    }
    else if(
            [ImageURLString rangeOfString: @".jpg" options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound || 
            [ImageURLString rangeOfString: @".jpeg" options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound
            )
    {
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 100) writeToFile: uniquePath atomically: YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you say your `UIImage` is autoreleased? I see only

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: data];
```

Use instead

```
UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData: data] autorelease];
```

As an alternative you may use:

```
UIImage *tmp = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: data];

UIImage *image = [self roundCorners: tmp];

[tmp release];
```

(assuming `roundCorners` returns an autoreleased object).

Comment: `- (UIImage*)roundCorners:(UIImage*)` better return an autoreleased object, too.

Comment: This is the way I had it.  When I do this, the app crashes the very first time the app is loaded onto the phone only.  It will not crash in the simulator.  Then every other app load from xcode after the first works fine.  Regardless, this caused the app to fail submission to the app store.

Comment: If I take the autorelease out, the app works as it should, installs fine the first time and works throughout.  But I am worried about a potential leak.  When I had it set to autorelease I had to enable zombies to figure out why the app was crashing and it stated:  [UIImage release]: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: @Jesse I edited the answer adding an alternative you may use. Check if it works fine for you.

Comment: Aha that was the culprit...I didnt even need the roundcorners anymore...I left the autorelease and took out the call to roundcorners and its fine now...thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

In your code, on the second line, your UIImage isn't autoreleased. As soon as you use alloc/init methods, you're retaining. Using a convenience method like imageNamed: creates an auto released object.